# Is there a way to count/return the most recent 10k items from an excel table with a criteria?

Tags: arrays, excel, sorting, excel-formula, countif

I have a large table in excel that is only getting larger. The data should probably exist in a database but right now I don't have that luxury. The data includes two columns I am interested in for this question, a categorical variable and a response variable. In this case my categorical variable is a part number and the response is a descriptor of that entry (good, bad or ugly).

I need to find the most recent 10k data points for each category and then return count the 'good' responses. I have a column for date and a column for time that I would like to use as my sort criteria.

Today, I add new data to my table and then manually use a table sort (very slow). Then off to the side of the table, I have a column for each of my categories with an If function to have a running total if the row matches the category. Separately I have match functions for each category to find the row where the count of 10k is reached. Finally, Offset functions to define the matched row as my ending point for a CountIf to count only the 'good' data points.

=COUNTIFS(OFFSET(Table1[@[category]],0,0,*row where 10k was found*),category1,OFFSET(Table1[@[response]],0,0,*row where 10k was found*),"Good")

I have 300k+ data points and as I mentioned, its only getting longer and my worksheet is only getting slower. I thought to use a worksheet SortBy function but it seems like you can't use an If in a SortBy? Unless there's a way to make a virtual array with if that can then be evaluated by SortBy?

I got this far with a virtual sorted column to evaluate but not sure this all works together...
=COUNTIF(OFFSET(FILTER(SORTBY(Table1,Table1[Day],-1,Table1[Time],-1),Table1[category]=category1),0,0,10000,1),"Good")

Table1 is my table of data. Trying to SortBy two levels, Date(day) then time. I want to filter out only data that meets my first category in A1. Then it gets messy because I want the Offset function to grab 10,000 cells but I don't know how to reference my virtual, filtered array... But if I could, then count the ones labeled as 'Good'.

Comment: Sorting is probably not slow, but recalculating IFs and MATCHes on 300,000 rows certainly is. On the Formulas tab, try changing calculation to manual, then sort, then Calculate Now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Count Recent

```
=LET(recent_count,G1,response,G2,
    h,TOROW(UNIQUE(Table1[Category])),
    cr,HSTACK(Table1[Category],Table1[Response]),
    s,SORTBY(cr,Table1[Day],-1,Table1[Time],-1),
    t,TAKE(s,recent_count),
    cc,INDEX(t,,1),
    r,INDEX(t,,2)=response,
    d,BYCOL(h,LAMBDA(c,SUM((cc=c)*r))),
VSTACK(h,d))
```

[image]

### EDIT

```
=LET(unique_col,Table1[Category],count_col,Table1[Response],
        sort_col1,Table1[Day],sort_col2,Table1[Time],
        recent_count,G1,response,G2,
    h,TOROW(UNIQUE(unique_col)),
    hsc,HSTACK(unique_col,count_col),
    sc,SORTBY(hsc,sort_col1,-1,sort_col2,-1),
    uc,INDEX(sc,,1),
    cc,INDEX(sc,,2),
    d,BYCOL(h,LAMBDA(c,LET(
        f,FILTER(cc,uc=c),
        t,TAKE(f,recent_count),
    COUNT(XMATCH(t,response))))),
VSTACK(h,d))
```

[image]

Comment: This looks pretty good, I must say I don't understand every step of how you are doing this but it seems like this is grabbing the most recent 15 data points then counting the responses in that set. I was looking for the most recent data points (10k in my case) for each category, then counting the responses that match my criteria in each set of 10k. Can your formula be modified to accommodate that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot use `COUNTIF` on a filtered result like `FILTER` or `SORTBY`.

Not sure if this is the most concise, but I believe this is what you want to do. See a couple of caveats at the bottom:

```
=LET(TOP,TAKE(SORTBY(Table1,Table1[Day],-1,Table1[Time],-1),10000),
COUNTA(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(TOP,(CHOOSECOLS(TOP,1)=$F2)*(CHOOSECOLS(TOP,2)=G$1)),1)))
```

`SORTBY` 2 columns (Day and Time)

`TAKE` the top 10,000 rows

`FILTER` that result by columns 1 & 2 (category and response)

`COUNTA` of the first column to get a count of how many rows meet the filter criteria.

Note this may not work properly if the category column has any blanks, or if there are no data points that meet the criteria (if there are 0 matching data points it will return 1)

[image]